# How to change the Overlay background of sweet alert jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, sweetalert

```
<script>    
swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
          icon: "success",
        });
      } else {
        swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
      }
    });
</script>
```

how to implement below method in above code.
i want to change the overlay background to different color.

```
.swal-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(43, 165, 137, 0.45);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)... My previous answer assumed [Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), which was wrong.

It's always a good thing to mention a reference to the plugin you ask about.

---

Now I understand that you would like to have an option for the backgroud-color when calling a Swal instance. That is not possible without re-ingineering the core code.

**But I found a trick**.

By defining a named function that sets a timeout to change the overlay color. The timeout is needed because we cannot change it before it exist (It's dynamically created).

So my idea to make it easy to use is to also define a color object that you will use to pick colors. And it makes the code easier to read.

```js
var SwalColors = {
  red: "rgba(250, 50, 50, 0.45)",
  green: "rgba(50, 250, 50, 0.45)",
  blue: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.45)"
};

function SwalOverlayColor(color){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".swal-overlay").css({"background-color":SwalColors[color]});
  },200);
}

SwalOverlayColor("blue");
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
  .then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    SwalOverlayColor("red");
    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    SwalOverlayColor("green");
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

So as you can see, the first Swal overlay is blue. If you click Ok, the next Swal overlay is red... Else if you click cancel, it is green.

You can define as many color as you whish, and refer to it using a readable property name... Just call the `SwalOverlayColor()` with a color name as argument right before the `swal()` call.

That is real close to have an option in the instance initialisation... Right?