# Change Background when landing on a page

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I would like to ask if on how to change my background when landing on a page. This is what it should like when the user tries to attempt to go on a page that needs to have an active session.
However, I want to hide the background. I want to show only the sweet alert pop up.
[image]

this is my page file.

**index.php**

```
<?php
  include 'includes/connection.php';
  if(!isset($_SESSION['student_id'])){
    echo '<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () {
        swal({
        title: "Access Failed",
        text: "You are not yet logged in! Redirecting to Login...",
        icon: "warning",
        button: false,
        timer: 2000
        }).then(function(result) {
            window.location = "Login.php?login=notactive";
        });';
    echo '}, 300);</script>';
    // echo "<script>alert('You are not logged in!'); location.href='Login.php';</script>";
  }
  else{
    $expire = 365*24*3600; // We choose a one year duration
    setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$expire); 
    // echo "<script>alert('You are already Logged in!'); location.href='Home.php';</script>";
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Repository Home</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="files/Images/logoapp.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="panel">
        <!-- Navbar Header -->
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-custom">
        <a href="index.php" target="_blank" class="navbar-brand ml-3"><img src="#" class="img-responsive" width="35" height="35">&nbsp; | Repo </img> </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" role="button" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px; margin: 0 auto;"></i></span>
        </button>
            <div id="navbarmenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center" style="width: 100%">
                    <li class="nav-item active px-3">
                        <a href="Home.php" class="nav-link text-nowrap"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown px-3">
                            <a href="repositorymanagement.php" class="nav-link text-nowrap"><i class="fas fa-laptop"></i>&nbsp;Research Repository </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <li id="irene"class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="../admin/repositorymanagement.php" class="nav-link text-nowrap"> Repository Management </a>
                    </li> -->
                    <li id="irene"class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="requestformmanagement.php" class="nav-link text-nowrap" ><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>&nbsp;Request Form Management </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown px-3 mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp; <?php include 'helper/current_user.php'; ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>&nbsp; Edit Profile</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-lock"></i>&nbsp; Edit Password</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout_student.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div class="container-sm" style="padding-top: 100px;">
        <div class="container-sm text-center">
            <div class="col-sm">
            <span id="HeaderBanner"> EMPOWERING WHAT'S NEXT </span>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="container-fluid" style="height: auto;width: 100%;">
                <div class="row">
                <div id="IntroductionParagraph" class="col-sm" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia at aspernatur veniam odit autem, earum explicabo maxime facilis molestiae hic quidem. Laboriosam dolores accusantium consequuntur, odio nulla in deserunt necessitatibus?
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum ducimus laudantium labore corporis voluptatem distinctio est praesentium ex. Sed est excepturi quidem labore blanditiis error voluptatibus facilis ipsum nemo consequatur? 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo culpa, totam alias voluptatum aperiam libero ipsa voluptatem perspiciatis. Quas doloremque dolore reiciendis tenetur accusantium ullam corporis adipisci natus officiis non?
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, repudiandae sint consectetur eius nostrum exercitationem quidem magnam ratione obcaecati maiores iure voluptatum laudantium minus nulla illo. Perferendis eligendi nam aspernatur.
                    </p>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime eius facere vitae corrupti adipisci, inventore minima laudantium quibusdam ad quas natus consequatur laborum qui dolor assumenda id nostrum sed ea.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam aperiam enim quod quae minus et perferendis magni eius, quibusdam est consequatur ab facilis nihil odit atque doloribus nesciunt ipsum. Maxime.
                    </p>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime eius facere vitae corrupti adipisci, inventore minima laudantium quibusdam ad quas natus consequatur laborum qui dolor assumenda id nostrum sed ea.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam aperiam enim quod quae minus et perferendis magni eius, quibusdam est consequatur ab facilis nihil odit atque doloribus nesciunt ipsum. Maxime.

                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mbPvK7Q/women-inoff.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #START# -----------ADDING OF MODAL ------------------# -->
    <!-- Large modal -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/responsive_modal.js">
        
    </script>
    <!-- #END# -------------ADDING OF MODAL ------------------# -->
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you need to change the background color of the sweet alert popup container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the following CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.swal-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}
</style>
```

Also, set the following options to prevent closing the modal on click or `Esc` key press.

```
swal({
        closeOnClickOutside: false,
        closeOnEsc: false,
        title: "Access Failed",
    .... rest of your code
```

*Without the options `closeOnClickOutside: false` and `closeOnEsc: false`, The page will be visible again if the user clicks outside the modal window (Sweet Alert) or press the `Esc` key.*

> By the way, I'd recommend using a PHP code checking for the active session (whether logged in or not) and redirect the user, rather than using the Javascript). Anyone with `javascript` disabled on their browser still can view the page content.

Comment: Hello @Ash1217, I would like to ask if it's possible to have the same transition when redirecting to the login? I've seen that after the sweetalert pop up is gone it stays for a millisecond to the current page before redirecting, the people can see a glimpse of it.

Comment: I just read your recommendation that I use a PHP Code, I am using PHP for active session and it's on the other file. For now, I am trying to redirect users who are not yet logged in to the login page. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.swal-overlay` class `background-color` property value
from
`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);`
to `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);`

```
.swal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    z-index: 10000;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried this property values but after running it the sweetalert won't pop up.

Comment: I have checked it and it is working file from my end.

Answer (score 0):

background color should be set while initializing the sweetalert

```
$(".swal-overlay").css({"background-color":rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52143162/1351883